# Javac classpath / cp option not able to find the source file

Tags: java

I have a source file Example.java in the following location:
`C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code\tutorial`
Result of dir command from tutorial directory:

```
Directory of C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code\tutorial
10/10/2020  01:51 PM    <DIR>          .
10/10/2020  01:51 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/10/2020  01:51 PM               133 Example.java        <- This is the source file
```

I am trying to compile this file from location C:\ .
The command that I am running from the command prompt is the following:

`C:\>javac -cp "C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code\tutorial" Example.java`

I am getting the following error:

```
error: file not found: Example.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classpath setting for `javac` is for finding other libraries and classes while compiling your `.java` files. It is not used for finding the `.java` files you specified as argument for the `javac` program. When you call `javac Example.java` and you are currently in the directory `C:\`, then it will look for a file `C:\Example.java`. It is most likely that the `Example.java` file will not be directly in the file system root `C:\`.

Either specify the `.java` files with an absolute path or adjust your working directory with `cd "C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code\tutorial\"` to go in that directory and compile the files from that location.

Comment: I was able to confirm from the javac --help that the intention of cp option is to find the .class files and not the .java source files. However, I was also able to find another option , -sourcepath, which is used to "Specify where to find input source files". I am assuming here that the source files here refer to the .java files. However, specifying the path using the sourcepath option did not help either. I was able to compile the file from the tutorial directory but wanted to play with these other options to compile the file from outside the directory.

Comment: It all makes sense now. These option are used to specify the path for  the classes that my current class depends on. To verify this, I created another package tutorial2 in the folder "Experimental Java code". In this package tutorial2 , I created another class Example2 containing a static method which I called in Example.java. Then, I compiled the file Example2.java and from the tutorial directory, I ran the following command: C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code\tutorial> javac -classpath "C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code"  Example.java. This worked as expected.

Comment: Note that I needed to compile Example2.java before compiling the Example.java file. However, I then tried to compile Example.java without compiling Example2.java manually. I simply gave java the sourcepath which tells java to look for dependencies as source files (.java) in the provided sourcepath. It then compiled Example2.java for me first and then used the .class file generated to compile Example.java. Thanks for helping out on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the absolute path to your .java file you should be able to just compile it without the -cp flag like so:

```
C:>javac "C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code\tutorial\Example.java"
```

Comment: I understand that. But what I don't undertand is why specifying the classpath option manually wouldn't help javac find it.

Comment: Also, if I go ahead and compile the file manually  in the directory tutorial and try to run the program using java as follows : C:> java -cp "C:\Users\sushr\Desktop\Experimental Java code" tutorial.Example , then it works. How come java is able to work with cp option while javac cannot ?

Comment: Ah didn't realize that's what you were asking. As the other answer said the -cp flag with javac doesn't search for your java files to compile - just the libraries/classes your code depends on.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, I have noticed that using the "~/" to shortcut to home, it does not work. For example:

```sh
javac -cp .:~/algs4/algs4.jar MyFile.java
```

Instead, I had to use the full path to locate the .jar file in order to compile:

```sh
javac -cp .:/Users/username/algs4/algs4.jar MyFile.java
```